# Create Command with CanExecute based on the Property of an item in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui

I have a ViewModel with a property of type `ObservableCollection<T>` called `Items` where `T` is a class that contains a property called `IsSelected` of type `bool` that raises the `PropertyChanged` event when it's value is changed.

I have a `Button` that is bound to a `Command` and I want that `Button` to be enabled if at least one of the `Items'` `IsSelected` property is `true` and disabled otherwise.
I'm trying to do this with `ReactiveCommand` from ReactiveUI so it would look something like this:

```
this.SubmitCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(SubmitItems,
     this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Items).Select(x => x.Any(i => i.IsSelected));
```

But this doesn't seem to work and I figure that's because the `Subscription` isn't monitoring the `IsSelected` property of the `Item` so when an `Item` is selected, there's no notification to the `Subscription`.
Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciate it.
I think this ReactiveUI stuff is really cool and I'm trying to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use DynamicData.

```cs
var canExecute = Items.ToObservableChangeSet()
  .AutoRefreshOnObservable(
    x => x.WhenAnyValue(item => item.IsSelected))
  .ToCollection()
  .Select(x => x.Any(item => item.IsSelected));
```

Comment: Works great Glenn.  Thanks!